# var newusername=$(this).val(); only sends out the value of the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Heres my problem, when im trying to send out my data to a PHP, its only sending the value of the `<button>` or `<input type="button">` .

And if i remove the definition of the variables it will only send the data as a string if i have them like thise

```
newusername: "newusername",
newpassword: "newpassword",
newclub: "newclub"
```

And if i remove the `""` I'll get an error in the jquery.mini.js

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Username </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newusername">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="newpassword">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Your club </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newclub">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn-reg">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log('Script loaded...');

$("#btn-reg").on("click", reg);      

function reg(newusername, newpassword, newclub) {
    console.log('Klick, klick...');
    var newusername = $(this).val();
    var newpassword = $(this).val();
    var newclub = $(this).val();

    $.post('classCalling.php', {
        newusername: "newusername",
        newpassword: "newpassword",
        newclub: "newclub"
    },
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: You're assigning `newusername`, `newpassword`, and `newclub` all to the "value" of the button you're clicking on. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: And you're passing a static string as an argunments

Comment: Im all new to this, so if you don't want to help.. dont even comment plz

Comment: Those arguments aren't valid for an event handler callback

Comment: Although sound cynical, those are in fact a valid points

Comment: @mackeemackee Who said anything about not helping? I'm asking a question. What do you expect those lines of code to do?

Comment: Need to show relevant html along with a proper description of expected results

Comment: Ok, sry Mike C. 

I was trying to define my data because i couldnt get the post to send anything but the strings

Comment: @mackeemackee Well, you need to give them the right data then. Do you have `<input>`s for your username/password/club? Do they have IDs or classes?

Comment: @mackeemackee So if you have a button with the ID of `btn-reg` and you're accessing it using `$('#btn-reg')` and you have a field with an ID of `newusername`, how do you think you could access it?

Comment: Share the html in the post, not in a comment without formatting

Answer (score 5):

I see two things:

- The definition of the object sent is bad. The object consists of key-value pairs which you set to a string value that is hardcoded.
- The capture of the variables at the beginning `$(this).val()` will all be the same. You didn't fetch this as a DOM object. You should do your CSS query in parenthesis (i.e. `$("---this--")`).

---

```
function reg(newusername, newpassword, newclub) {

    console.log('Klick, klick...');

    // if there is a input with class newusernameand only one
    var newusername = $('input.newusername').val();

    //if there is a input with class newpassword and only one
    var newpassword = $('input.newpassword').val();

    //if there is a input with class newclub and only one
    var newclub = $('input.newclub').val();

    $.post('classCalling.php',
        {
            newusername: newusername,
            newpassword: newpassword,
            newclub: newclub
        },
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

Comment: need to prevent default also or OP page will reload

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is for a form you can simplify the data by using [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) which will send the same keys as the names of the input controls

```
<form id="password-form">
   <input name="newusername">
   <input name="newpassword">
   <select name="newclub"></select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#password-form').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); // stop default from reloading page
   var postData = $(this).serialize();
   $.post('classCalling.php', postData , function(response){
          console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Or written using `reg()` as event handler function:

```
function reg(event){
   event.preventDefault(); // stop default from reloading page
   var postData = $(this).serialize();
   $.post('classCalling.php', postData , function(response){
       console.log(response);
   });
}

$('#password-form').submit(reg);
```

It is better to bind to submit event so user won't bypass click using keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass these variables as arguments. Also, you are passing strings to the backend, what cannot work. Further, you are not selecting the values of input fields but of the button itself.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="newusername" />
    <input type="password" class="newpassword" />
    <input type="text" class="newclub" />
    <button class="btn-reg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
console.log('Script loaded...');

$(".btn-reg").on("click", reg);      

function reg(event) {
    console.log('Klick, klick...');

    event.preventDefault(); // prevents the form to be submitted

    var newusername = $(".newusername").val();
    var newpassword = $(".newpassword").val();
    var newclub = $(".newclub").val();

    $.post('classCalling.php', {
            newusername: newusername,
            newpassword: newpassword,
            newclub: newclub
        },
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How can a button possibly contain all those variable values?

Comment: Yes, the arguments are pointless. No, you can actually send strings back to the backend (ultimately, that's all you're doing). But the problem is that they need the *right* strings.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I have overseen, that he didn't read the arguments correct. I fixed it.

Comment: must also prevent default

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a conceptual error on how event handlers work in jQuery.

By calling `$("#btn-reg").on("click", reg);`,

You are telling jQuery to call the method `reg` whenever the `#btn-reg` button is pressed. When this happens, jQuery will call `reg` while passing on the element that was pressed. (This is to support multiple event handlers calling one method, for example if you had 2 buttons).

Therefore, by using `$(this)`, you are actually calling `$("#btn-reg")`.

`$(this).val();` would therefore give you the value of the `<button>`, which you are assigning to the three variables `newusername`, `newpassword`, and `newclub`. - This explains why you are seeing the value of the `<button>` on your PHP script.

---

While you have not provided the HTML content of your form, below is an example of how I would do it with a simple 3-field form submitted via javascript:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="newusername" />
<input type="text" id="newpassword" />
<input type="text" id="newclub" />
<button id="btn-reg">Submit</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
console.log('Script loaded...');

$("#btn-reg").on("click", reg);      

function reg(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Klick, klick...');

    // You are declaring new variables here
    var newusername = $("#newusername").val();
    var newpassword = $("#newpassword").val();
    var newclub = $("#newclub").val();

    // And using them here. The format used here is
    // <name to submit>: <value to submit>
    // That is why the variable names should not be quoted on the right
    $.post('classCalling.php', {
        newusername: newusername,
        newpassword: newpassword,
        newclub: newclub
    },
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: need to prevent the default event

Comment: It worked great! Thx for the lecture, i think i got a better grip of that part now! Thanks @shrmn

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to ask if you need any further clarifications on what the code does :) @mackeemackee Do mark it as an accepted answer if you deem it suitable

Answer (score -5):

```
var newusername="newusername"; // or get your needed value anywhere else
var newpassword="newpassword"; // or get your needed value anywhere else
var newclub="newclub"; // or get your needed value anywhere else

$("#btn-reg").on("click", function () {

$.post('classCalling.php', {

    newusername: newusername,
    newpassword: newpassword,
    newclub: newclub
},
function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

It will help you.

Comment: It won't help nobody

Comment: these are still hard coded strings and the variables will only be defined on page load before any user data is entered

Comment: All you did was put the (invalid) declarations outside of the function. How will this help?